# Combine Lucene query with different analyzer

Tags: lucene

I have a Lucene (3.5.0) index where the document is indexed using the standard analyzer and some other fields with a different analyzer.Io I would like to compose a query (or a combination of query) that goes to look for in the two cases with AND logic. I tried a lot in the literature, but it does not seem to be a situation handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [`BooleanQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html) to combine different queries together.

You just need to add your different queries to it using the `add` method and specifying whether the query must, should or must not match.